# Would it be a good idea to migrate Korean-related questions posted on Linguistics SE?

Tags: discussion, support, migration

In [Linguistics Beta Stack Exchange (LSE)](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/), there are questions that could be posted on Korean Language Beta Stack Exchange (KSE) as follows:

[Irregular Fortition(경음화, 된소리 되기) in Modern Korean](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/12410/irregular-fortition%EA%B2%BD%EC%9D%8C%ED%99%94-%EB%90%9C%EC%86%8C%EB%A6%AC-%EB%90%98%EA%B8%B0-in-modern-korean)

[Rules of Yale Romanization of Korean](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2091/rules-of-yale-romanization-of-korean)

[Criteria for separating Korean words](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2777/criteria-for-separating-korean-words)

[How did Korean become a language isolate?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/294/how-did-korean-become-a-language-isolate)

[The true place of articulation of Korean affricates](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/8975/the-true-place-of-articulation-of-korean-affricates)

[How to distinguish Korean “ㅔ” /e/ and “ㅐ” /ɛ/?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2619/how-to-distinguish-korean-%E3%85%94-e-and-%E3%85%90-%C9%9B)

[Does Korean have two classes of adjectives correlating to the -i and -na adjectives of Japanese?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6904/does-korean-have-two-classes-of-adjectives-correlating-to-the-i-and-na-adjecti)

[What was the most usual and most recent system of writing Korean without any hangul at all?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6844/what-was-the-most-usual-and-most-recent-system-of-writing-korean-without-any-han)

[Korean syllable-final ㅅ in Hangul transcription of loanwords](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2805/korean-syllable-final-%E3%85%85-in-hangul-transcription-of-loanwords)

[Where can orthographic Korean words be split at the end of a line?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2903/where-can-orthographic-korean-words-be-split-at-the-end-of-a-line)

[Looking for korean text corpus](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/14982/looking-for-korean-text-corpus)

[Why was korea able to remove kanji but japan wasn't when both languages use homophones?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3831/why-was-korea-able-to-remove-kanji-but-japan-wasnt-when-both-languages-use-homo)

Some might say that a few of them are more closely related with LSE than KSE, but all of them are related with the Korean language in one way or another.

Would it be a good idea to migrate Korean-related questions posted on LSE to KSE? What would be an ideal way to do that?

Comment: lets just cross post all the questions and answers here and get more views

Answer (score 5):

If these questions are on topic at Linguistics, they should stay on Linguistics.  Beta sites are expected to grow organically, by new questions and answers being posted - not by acquiring a data dump from another site.

The SE position on this is stated in [Respect the community - your own, and others’](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/), which says in part

> **don't attempt to scavenge on-topic questions from other sites** by asking the moderators there to migrate them to yours.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I learn one thing every day.